# Issues with uninstalling Blackfire on Laravel Forge

Tags: laravel, forge, blackfire

I'm trying to remove the Blackfire profiler that was installed on the server via Laravel Forge.
Under "Integrations" I clicked "Uninstall" on Blackfire and restarted PHP, but now I'm getting the following warning on Sentry:

```
Core Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'blackfire.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/blackfire.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/blackfire.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20190902/blackfire.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/blackfire.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))
```

I have checked the `php.ini` file and can find no reference to Blackfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for references in phpinfo:

```
php -i | grep 'blackfire'
```

Output:

```
/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-blackfire.ini
```

Find out what is trying to load it:

```
php --ini
```

Output:

```
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d
```

Delete config file:

```
sudo rm /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/99-blackfire.ini
```

Repeat for `fpm` version:

```
sudo rm /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d/99-blackfire.ini
```

Restart PHP